# Insert data frame to database with different columns

Tags: pandas

I am trying to insert records from a `pandas` dataframe to a database table. However, the dataframe and the table structure does not 100% match. I could iterate/chunk the records and insert that way, but that seems very manual. Is there a better way to map columns to a table?

**Data frame**

```
| column_1 | column_2 |
|----------|----------|
```

**Database table**

```
| column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | created_at |
|----------|----------|----------|------------|
```

Something like this would probably work but has to be inefficient

```
for row in data_frame:
    insert into db_table (column_1, column_2) VALUES (row['column_1'], row['column_2'])
```

Comment: If you can't bulk-insert items, you can't get any faster than that :(

Answer (score 0):

I would upsert using sqlalchemy. Lets assume;

1. column_1 is the primary key,
2. I have coerced the source data which is the dataframe table to the target tables (database table's) dtypes. I would use the query below;

`from sqlalchemy import create_engine`

`#Create connection`

`conn = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://Server_name/Database_Name?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0`')

```
#Read dataframe


df_to_ be_written = pd.read_csv()
#Write Dataframe to database as tempstaging table


 df_to_ be_written.to_sql('df1', conn, if_exists='append', index = False)
```

`#Upsert Query`
sql = '''

```
declare @changes table(Change varchar(30))
    MERGE database_table_to update  AS TARGET
    USING df1 AS SOURCE
    ON (TARGET.column_1 = SOURCE.column_1)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
       THEN  INSERT (column_1, column_2)  
             VALUES (SOURCE.column_1, SOURCE.column_2)
    WHEN MATCHED  
       THEN UPDATE SET 
            column_2      = SOURCE.column_2,
            
       
    OUTPUT $action into @changes;
    COMMIT;
    select Change, count(*) impacted
    from @changes
    group by Change
```

'''

```
conn.execute(sql)
```