# if my db and dataframe column is different length can i append the value to db

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**If database and dataframe column is not in equal can i add the value from dataframe to db using DataFrame.to_sql for appending the value**

**DATABASE -**

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

**DataFrame -**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 8 |
| 9 | 10 |

now to can we my dataframe has 2 column and my db has 3 column can i append the value uing DataFrame.to_sql

Comment: Yes, you can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69982467/insert-data-frame-to-database-with-different-columns

Comment: Only if your database accepts NULL values for the column. (You have 2 Column B?)

Comment: @Corralien sry it is column c

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that if your columns allow null values.

Here is a complete example. Column B allows empty values while columns A and C do not:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy import insert, select
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
meta = MetaData()

mytable = Table('mytable', meta,
    Column('A', Integer, nullable=False),
    Column('B', Integer, nullable=True),  # Allow null values
    Column('C', Integer, nullable=False)
)

meta.create_all(engine)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(insert(mytable).values([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]))
    curr = conn.execute(select(mytable))

    # Integrity error, failed because C is missing
    try:
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [7, 9], 'B': [8, 10]})
        df1.to_sql('mytable', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
    except IntegrityError as err:
        print(err)

    # Worked because B allows null values
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [11, 13], 'C': [12, 14]})
    df2.to_sql('mytable', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)

    # Dump database
    df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM mytable', conn)
    print(df)
```

Output:

```
(sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: mytable.C
[SQL: INSERT INTO mytable ("A", "B") VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ((7, 8), (9, 10))]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)

    A    B   C
0   1  2.0   3  # existing data
1   4  5.0   6  # existing data
2  11  NaN  12  # data from df2
3  13  NaN  14  # data from df2
```